# How can raw binary data be retrieved from an array buffer?

Tags: javascript, blob, arraybuffer

In trying to send document scans as binary data over a web socket the first block of code below works fairly well. Since the first byte contains information concerning what exactly to do with the blob, the image data starts at an offset of one byte; and because it appears that `blob.slice()` returns a copy of the original blob rather than simply reading it, this likely is not the most efficient method of processing the blob because it makes a copy of the entire blob less one byte.

```
  socket.onmessage = function(evt) {
    if (evt.data instanceof Blob) {
      evt.data.slice(0,1).arrayBuffer()
        .then( (b) => {
          let v = new DataView(b),
              r = v.getUint8(0);
          // Do something based on r and then display scan.
          let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL( evt.data.slice(1) );
          imgscan.onload = () => {
            URL.revokeObjectURL( objectURL );
          };
          imgscan.src = objectURL;
        })
```

If the websocket's `binaryType` is changed to `arraybuffer`, it's a bit easier to read the first byte and apparently does not make a copy, but I do not understand how to get the image data out of the buffer to display it; that is, I don't see which method to apply to the `DataView` to get the raw binary data of the image. Would you please explain or point me to the correct documentation? Thank you.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533552/which-typed-array-should-i-use-for-arraybuffer-of-image-files) seems similar but was not helpful to me anyway.

```
  socket.onmessage = function(evt) {
    if ( evt.data instanceof ArrayBuffer ) {
      let v = new DataView(evt.data),
          r = v.getUint8(0);
       // How to get the raw binary image data out of 
       // the array buffer starting at the first byte?
```

Comment: You can read the data without copying with typed arrays (`new Uint8Array(evt.data, 1)`), but I don’t think you can display it in an img element without creating a new blob. (The other options are data URLs and JavaScript decoding onto a canvas, which are worse.)

Comment: @Ry- Thank you. I came across some examples that print the bits using `getInt8()` but that doesn't seem helpful. If the array buffer has to be converted to a new blob, then it would appear that there is no advantage to setting the socket's `binaryType`  to `arraybuffer`. It's quick enough as is and I' likely wasting time trying to optimize something that cannot be changed. It makes me wonder if sending the data as text with the image as base64 would be more efficient. It's, I think, 33% larger but wouldn't need to be copied to separate the equivalent of the first byte.

Comment: Also, thank you to whoever removed the duplicate question from this one, because I did not find an answer in that question/answer.

Comment: It would need to be decoded, which is a copy plus extra overhead. I would say don’t worry about the copy.